# IPP V3 devkit Delete all entity in as bulk delete

Tags: quickbooks, intuit-partner-platform, quickbooks-online

Is there any API which delete QBO company existing account/data/entity in bulk before uploading the data ?

Can you provide sample code and ref. url

Answer (score 1):

Using QBO V3 Batch, you can delete accounts in group.

You can refer the following two url.

Batch - https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0025_quickbooksapi/0055_devkits/0201_ipp_java_devkit_3.0/0001_synchronous_calls/batch_process

Account Ref - https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0025_quickbooksapi/0050_data_services/030_entity_services_reference/account

PN - Delete is achieved by setting the  attribute to false in an entity update request; thus, making it inactive. In this type of delete, the record is not permanently deleted, but is hidden for display purposes.

Request URI : https://quickbooks.api.intuit.com/v3/company/<**relamId**>/batch?

```
Account account;
        try {
            List<Account> findAll = service.findAll(new Account());
            account = findAll.get(0);

            BatchOperation batchOperation = new BatchOperation();
            account.setActive(false);
            batchOperation.addEntity(account, OperationEnum.UPDATE, "1");
            service.executeBatch(batchOperation);
        } catch (FMSException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Thanks